# Contains tag on SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

Currently there is a [contains](/questions/tagged/contains) on SO.

It seems to represent several separate things in several languages.

- Is a point contained in a shape?
- Does a string contain another string?
- Does a list/collection/object contain another object?

Should the tag be removed or re-tagged to only mean one of those things.  Currently it seems useless to me.

Comment: Related discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63056/tag-banishment-request-exists

Answer (score 2):

Kill it with fire.